# How to construct irregular shapes in HTML tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to duplicate the table below in HTML: [image]
But there are a couple of extra-irregular shaped rows that I'm wondering if there's an easy way to code them using tables, particularly the Schools swim on Friday, and the rentals in the evening on Monday-Thursday.

I know how to use **colspan** and **rowspan** but is there some kind of grid design trick in tables these days?

What's the best way to code a table with unorthodox shapes for rows and columns like above?

Here's what I've built so far, but I don't know how to make the extra irregular shapes:

```css
table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 2px solid #263333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.schedule td {
  width: 16.6666666%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.schedule tr {
  height: 3em
}
.schedule tr {
  height: 3em
}
.schedule thead tr {
  height: 1em;
  color: #f2f5f7;
  background: #263333
}
.noborder {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="schedule">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4 rowspan=2>
        <p>Early Bird Swim</p>
        <p>6:00am-8:30am</p>
        <td>Early Bird Swim
          <br>6:00am-7:30am</td>
        <td rowspan=2>Early Bird Swim
          <br>6:00am-8:30am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Staff Meeting 7:30am-8:30am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4 rowspan=2>Cardston Schools 8:30am-3:00pm</td>
      <td>Cardston Schools 8:30am-12:00pm</td>
      <td>Rentals 10:00am-12:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>Lane Swim / Parent & Tot 12:00-1:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4>Swim Club 3:15-5:00pm</td>
      <td colspan=2>Public Swim 1:00-5:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=6>Lane Swim 5:00-6:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Family 6-8:00pm</td>
      <td colspan=5>Public Swim 6:00pm-8:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aqua Fit 8-9</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Aqua Fit 8-9</td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan=2>Rentals 8:00-10:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4>Rentals Until 10:00pm</td>
      <td colspan=2>Rentals 9:00-10:00pm</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This can all be achieved using colspan &/or multiple tables.

Comment: Or by removing/adding borders with CSS, but I don't know if that's allowed.

Comment: colspan and rowspan are all you need

Comment: See, my damie, @PootieTang don't wa-da-tah to the shama cow... 'cause thats a cama cama leepa-chaiii, dig?

Comment: sa-da-tay, my damie

Answer (score 2):

You can use colspan and rowspan, but for certain cells, you'll need custom CSS for each cell. You can control the thickness and color of each side of the td cell:

```
.some-class {
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
border-right: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

etc., or in shorthand:

```
border: 1px 1px 0px 1px solid #000;
```

Comment: I was hoping there'd be some wizard way to do it without styles.

Comment: No, but I would identify common patterns, and then name and use accordingly. For instance, if you have a three-sided cell without a left border, you can call it .td-no-left and reuse it anytime you have a cell that needs to keep the left border open.